# Losing Aliases when trying to group-by rows in linq sql query, how to group-by rows in this case

Tags: sql, linq, count, group-by

I am a newbie intern way over my head, I promise I have researched this thoroughly and tried many different things. The following linq query works, but I want to group rows by last and first name and then only show the rows that appear more than once. When I un-comment out the group by statement, all my aliases below become unrecognized and changing them to the actual db.table names doesn't help.

```
 var query = from emps in db.Employees

              join c in db.Cards on emps.SbiID equals c.SbiID

              where c.StateID == 0 && c.CardNumberNumeric > 100000

             //group emps by new {emps.Surname, emps.Name}; 

             //orderby grp.Count()  // something like 'where grp.Count > 1

              select new 
              { 

                  Surname = emps.Surname,
                  Name = emps.Name,
                  CorpID = emps.Identifier,
                  CardNum = c.CardNumber,
                  CostCenter = emps.EmployeeUserField.UF13,
                  Supervisor = (from e in db.Employees
                               where                                                  
                               e.Identifier.Equals(emps.EmployeeUserField.UF5)
                               select e.Surname).FirstOrDefault()
                               + ", "
                               + (from e in db.Employees
                                  where e.Identifier.Equals(emps.EmployeeUserField.UF5)
                                  select e.Name).FirstOrDefault(),

                 SupervisorID = emps.EmployeeUserField.UF5,
                 EmpCommence = emps.CommencementDateTime,
                 CardCommence = c.CommencementDateTime,
                 WorkPhone = emps.Telephone,
                 State = (from cf in db.ComboFields
                          from sp in db.StringProperties
                          where cf.ComboIndex.Equals(c.StateID)
                          && cf.StringID.Equals(sp.StringID)
                          && cf.TableName.Equals("Card")
                          && cf.FieldName.Equals("StateID")

                         select sp.DefaultValue).FirstOrDefault()                                       

             };          

 this.tagsGridView.DataSource = query;
 this.tagsGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're running into is that you're not flattening out your groups appropriately. For example:

```
var duplicateEmployees = db.Employees
    .GroupBy(emp => emp, new EmployeeComparer())
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(grp => grp.AsEnumerable());

var duplicateEmployeeInfo =
    from emps in duplicateEmployees
    join c in db.Cards on emps.SbiID equals c.SbiID
    where c.StateID == 0 && c.CardNumberNumeric > 100000
    select new
    {
        ... what to select
    };
```

With:

```
public class EmployeeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
{
    public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
    {
        return x.Surname == y.Surname && x.Name == y.Name;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
    {
        unchecked { return (17 * obj.Surname.GetHashCode()) ^ (23 * obj.Name.GetHashCode()); }
    }
}
```

This groups the employees by name, finds the groups that have a count > 1, then returns the elements of those groups. No guarantees on performance, but this should solve your issue.

Comment: thanks for the help; however I am getting an error 'cannot access a disposed object'  [ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'DataContext accessed after Dispose.'.] Was wondering if you knew what might be causing this and how to fix.